# Load individual series data as clicked in legend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

Initialized my series with no data.  I want to load the data on an as needed basis when I click a legend item.  Clicking legend item does trigger "legendItemClick" as expected but I really need an "onClick" with the calling component.

When the legend changes in

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'   
...
import Config from './configBHMTrend.js';
...
loadIndividualTag(tagName) {...}
...
render(){
....
return(
    <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={config} />
)
```

Comment: Can you check if your function works here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-legenditemclick/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default `visible` option for the series to `false` and in `legendItemClick` event use `setData` method:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        visible: false,
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function() {
                this.setData([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/2100/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData